# LyX cannot compile correctly my title page

Tags: lyx, titles, compiling

I am trying to make the title page for my master thesis. I found on the internet a template, in which the cover page is given by the following code

```
\begin{titlepage} 
\begin{center}

\textsc{\LARGE University Name}\\[1.5cm] 
\textsc{\Large Master Thesis}\\[0.5cm] 


{\huge \bfseries Thesis Title}\\[0.4cm] 


\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\begin{flushleft} \large 
\emph{Author: Name} 
\end{flushleft} 
\end{minipage} 

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\begin{flushright} \large 
\emph{Supervisor: Name}
\end{flushright} 
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]   

\large \textit{Department of Economics}\\[0.4cm] 
\textit{Uppsala}\\[0.4cm]


{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date %\includegraphics{Logo} 

\vfill 
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

When I compile latex in Lyx, my name and my supervisor's name are aligned in the center and not in the left and right, as they supposed to be

What I am missing?

PS: Here is the link [enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/2760564pfctnc#/7379362/)

Comment: Remove the empty line between the two `minipage`s containing the two names. Empty line --> paragraph break.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remains. PS: Thanks for editing my question

Comment: Hm, are you sure? Can you edit your question to include the exact code demonstrating the problem? When I remove that empy line in the code in a test document the two names are placed next to each other, as expected.

Comment: I don't know if it matters that I use koma-script document class.. Or maybe I have to put the code in the latex preamble...

Comment: Shouldn't matter.

Comment: You haven't removed the empty line between `\end{minipage}` and `\begin{minipage}`.

Comment: Yes it worked!!! Could you explain why I had to remove the empty line?

Comment: As I said, an empty line in (La)TeX code signifies a paragraph break, and new paragraphs start on a new line.

Comment: Also, consider inserting `\hfill` between the two `minipage`s.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thank you very much for your recommendation. I wasn't aware of this command. I also used '\hrulefill' above and below my title